# Flutter how i can get context in PopupMenuButton widget?

Tags: flutter

I have a PopupMenuButton. But if I want to call a method that will jump to
another page

`Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SingleOrder()),);`

I have an error. Undefined name `context`. How can I get the context in `Navigator.push`?

```
Widget _childPopup() => PopupMenuButton<int>(

 onSelected: (result) {
  if (result == 0) {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SingleOrder()),
   );
 }
},

itemBuilder: (context) => [
  PopupMenuItem(
   value: 0,
    child: Text(
    "MENU 1",
    style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black54),
  ),
),
PopupMenuItem(
  value: 1,
  child: Text(
    "MENU 2",
    style: TextStyle(
        color:  Colors.black54),
    ),
  ),
],
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `BuildContext` to your `_childPopup` function. You likely defined this function in a place where `BuildContext` is not directly available. Ex.

```
Widget _childPopup(BuildContext context) => PopupMenuButton<int>(

 onSelected: (result) {
  if (result == 0) {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SingleOrder()),
   );
 }
},

itemBuilder: (context) => [
  PopupMenuItem(
   value: 0,
    child: Text(
    "MENU 1",
    style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black54),
  ),
),
PopupMenuItem(
  value: 1,
  child: Text(
    "MENU 2",
    style: TextStyle(
        color:  Colors.black54),
    ),
  ),
],
);
```

Doing this ensures that `BuildContext` will be available to the function and allows you to better control which context it will use.